# please check why import react is not working

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, frontend, components, jsx

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function Header(){
    return(
        <header>
        <nav className="nav">
            <img src="react.png" className="nav-logo"></img>
            <ul className="nav-items">
                <li>Pricing</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav> 
    </header>
    )
}
function Footer(){
    return(
        <footer className="footer">
            <small><p className="foot-text">all rights reserved.</p></small> 
        </footer>
    )
}
function MainContent(){
    return(
        <div className="main-content">
         <h1 className="main-head">I LOVE REACT! because:</h1>
                <ol>
                    <li>it is declarative</li>
                    <li>we can work on composable pieces and then<br/>bind them together to make a whole.</li>
                    <li>it supports dynamic rendering</li>
                    <li>supports jsx</li>
                </ol>
        </div>
    )
}
function Page(){
    return(
        <> 
                <Header/>
                <MainContent/>  
                <Footer/>
            </>
          
       

    )
}
//<> </> =fragment <div> can also be used
ReactDOM.render(<Page/>,document.getElementById("root"));
```

Actually the output is not rendered into the screen but if i include cdns into html and comment the import statements then it works perfect

cdns imported in html file are:

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
```

### error

(node:18960) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
c:\Users\KIIT\Desktop\PROJECTS\React codecamp\index.js:1
import React from "react";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:77:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:20)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1340:27)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49

Node.js v20.10.0

Answer (score 0):

Add `"type":"module"` to your `package.json` file.